# What is the purpose of app.synth() in AWS CDK?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

What is the purpose of the `app.synth()` line in AWS CDK applications? For example it can be seen here on line 29:
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/ecs/fargate-application-load-balanced-service/index.ts

I have looked at the CDK docs but I cannot find what the actual purpose of that function is. As I understand it, the app is automatically synthesized upon `cdk deploy` or `cdk synth`. I also took the example shown in repo linked above, commented out the `app.synth()` line, deployed it, and it seemed to work as expected. Therefore I'm wondering if I'm missing something when it comes to the purpose of app.synth()

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear about the difference?

Comment: I'm still confused as to why every example app incldues app.synth() at the end if cdk deploy synthesizes it anyways. Why include that at all in the code then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[cdk synth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/hello_world.html#hello_world_tutorial_synth) **only constructs your CloudFormation template**. It does not deploy (create actual resources) it to AWS. You can take the template constructed, deploy it manually in CFN console, edit or inspect.

[cdk deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/hello_world.html#hello_world_tutorial_deploy) is going to construct the template and **deploy it to AWS** as well.

People use `synth` with `deploy` because it is a **good practice**:

> It is optional (though **good practice**) to synthesize before deploying. The AWS CDK synthesizes your stack before each deployment.

Comment: So if I was only going to use CDK deploy, the `app.synth()` line wouldn't be necessary right?

Comment: @JamalH Yes. You can deploy without synth.

Comment: @JamalH I edited the answer. It is simply good practice to do this. Probably you can detect some errors before you actually try to deploy your stack.

Answer (score 13):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked, but I was curious and looked into it myself, so I'll share it with you.
(I also thought that the current accepted answer was about the CDK CLI and not about the CDK application code.)

The `App` class has an option called `autoSynth` which is set to `true` by default, so even if you omit `app.synth()` in your code, it will be executed automatically.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.AppProps.html#autosynth

As mentioned in the documentation, this feature may not work in some languages, so it seems to be explicitly specified in many sample codes.

According to the documentation, it is OK to run `app.synth()` multiple times.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.App.html#synthoptions

`autoSynth` works fine on Node.js.
It is implemented in Node.js using `process.once("beforeExit", listener)`.
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v2.51.1/packages/@aws-cdk/core/lib/app.ts#L166-L170

I started this investigation because when I ran CDK in Deno, I had to explicitly run `app.synth()` to generate the CDK assembly. As a result of this investigation, I found out that this is because the Node compatibility layer in Deno does not currently support "beforeExit" events.
https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/blob/113435ada1948b90188586f022d55745c6d2d19b/node/process.ts#L51-L52

As per this experience, it is better to explicitly call `app.synth()` as recommended.

Comment: had the same question about `app.synth()`. This was very helpful for me. Thank's for sharing!

Comment: Just want to highlight that the autoSynth is set as true by default if running the app via CDK CLI, not otherwise.

**************** From the docs (typescript) ****************************
     * @default true if running via CDK CLI (`CDK_OUTDIR` is set), `false`
     * otherwise